# Error while searching for windows updates available using ansible task and win_updates module

Tags: windows, ansible

I am using ansible win_updates module and encountering error as shown further down, any idea why this happens?

```
  - name: Check for available updates
  ansible.windows.win_updates:
    state: searched
    category_names:
      - SecurityUpdates
      - CriticalUpdates
  register: update_check
```

Error is as below.

```
    TASK [windows_patching_role : Check for available updates] ****************************************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 761
fatal: [sgldc01]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  failed_update_count: 0
  filtered_updates: {}
  found_update_count: 0
  installed_update_count: 0
  msg: 'Searching for updates: Exception from HRESULT: 0x8024402C - Same as ERROR_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED - the proxy server or target server name cannot be resolved (WU_E_PT_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED 8024402C)'
  reboot_required: false
  updates: {}
```